# Concatenate two json object and return as json object and return as response in angular

Tags: angularjs

```
$http({ 
    method: "get",
    url: "/Home/GetCallInfo"
}).then(function (response) {

}, function () {
     alert("error");
})

public string GetCallInfo (Object result1,Object result2)
{
     // Here i want to return like 
    return js.Serialize(result1) + "^" + js.Serialize(result2)

}
```

it displays alert error .
What to do ? I am new in angular. Plz reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is trying to parse the response as JSON. Try this:

```
$http({
    method: "get",
    url: "/Home/GetCallInfo",
    transformResponse: [function (data) {
        return data.split("^");
    }]
});
```

This overrides the default behaviour of trying to parse a JSON (which is not, because of the `^` in the middle), and splits it instead.

However, keep in mind that this is a naive implementation. Having one of the JSONs containing `^` inside will break this. Try to think a better implementation along these lines.